# What is a good Apple podcast to listen to on a daily basis?

Tags: podcasts

If I have time to listen to just one podcast a day or every other day about Apple stuff, which one should I listen to?  I know there's a lot of different specialized Apple podcasts out there (i.e. Mac downloads, iOS apps, Apple news, etc.), but can anyone recommend a general podcast which has elements of all of these?  I'd also be interested in the best podcasts in certain specialized areas, but mostly I'm looking for one that I can listen to consistently and find out most of what is going on in the Apple world.

Comment: I believe this to be off topic and very subjective, though others may feel differently. [Meta discussion](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84/on-topic-or-off).

Comment: Since your question is intended to gather a list of relevant answers, this should be marked [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I converted this question.

Answer (score 4):

[MacBreak Weekly](http://twit.tv/mbw) seems to fit the bill except it's, er, weekly. I don't know of any daily podcasts.

Comment: I had to stop listening to MBW because Leo will not quit talking about iPhones and iPads.  They should just change the name to ios weekly.

Answer (score 2):

### Mac OS Ken

I really like the podcast Mac OS Ken. From the description on iTunes...

> This is daily Apple news. Monday
> through Friday, Ken Ray brings
> commute-sized tech news to the
> podsphere. If it's Apple news,
> Apple-related news, or news related to
> Apple-related news, you'll hear about
> it here. News you'll like... this is
> Mac OS Ken.

It is free five times per week with a 'Day 6' show available to paid subscribers. The podcast is very well-done, informative and entertaining with a bit of humor.

On iTunes: [Mac OS Ken](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/mac-os-ken/id120867842)

Web site: [Mac OS Ken](http://macosken.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Hypercritical](http://5by5.tv/hypercritical) from 5by5 is excellent, John Siracua is a great analyst

Answer (score 0):

These aren't released daily, but I also like the MacCast, and MacGeekGab.

I still listen to MacBreak Weekly, but I listen more for Andy Ihnatko than Leo Laporte.  Leo is a radio and TV guy who talks for a living. Andy studies technology and is an [amazing writer](http://www.cwob.com).

EDIT: As a newbie to this forum, I can't post more than one hyperlink yet (Even though I belong to several other StackExchange sites), but the podcasts are all available through iTunes. I'll leave the link to Andy's blog.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

I'm not sure about the "daily" but TED talks are very good. They have multiple "streams" for audio, video, and high definition video.

Comment: In what way is that Apple related?